# Windows Filtering Platform: Access to the the packet's payload

Tags: windows, ndis, wfp

I'm traversing through a NET_BUFFER's MDL chain to get the associated data.
The two macros that are used to indicate where the *used data space* begins (`NET_BUFFER_DATA_OFFSET()` & `NET_BUFFER_CURRENT_MDL_OFFSET()`) got me a little confused, as I've always observed them returning the same value, and both seem equally usable.

Which one should be used? What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it.
Obviously if *current mdl* doesn't point to the first mdl, then `NET_BUFFER_DATA_OFFSET()` will indicate the size of all mdl's until the current one, plus the current's own offset, while `NET_BUFFER_CURRENT_MDL_OFFSET()` will indicate only the offset within the current mdl, which is all you really need if you use `NET_BUFFER_CURRENT_MDL()` macro.
An optimization thingy.